# Voltage of thermocouple

Tags: voltage, current, temperature, thermocouple

As we know, when we use a thermocouple, we measure mV value.

This is what I wonder.

Why we measure voltage not current?
Like voltage, I think the current of T/C is proportional to temperature too.

Answer (score 4):

The current (if terminated in some kind of load or a short) will be dependent on the resistance of the thermocouple wire and connections, which will vary with the temperature along the length of the wires, the soundness of the connections, diameter of the wires and so on.

The voltage is **only** dependent on the temperatures at the hot and cold junctions and the wire composition.

Of course if you measure the current into a resistance that is much larger than the thermocouple resistance, then you are effectively measuring the voltage and it will work well.

You can still find self-powered temperature gauges that use a meter movement that operates directly from the thermocouple, and thus measures the current through a copper coil and the thermocouple wire. To achieve accuracy they're sometimes marked with the nominal resistance of the thermocouple that they expect (eg. 10\$\Omega\$). They need temperature compensation for the positive TCR of copper and some kind of bimetal mechanism for cold-junction compensation.

Comment: What does "soundness of the connections" mean? I googled for soundness, but only found a mathematical meaning I cannot see how it applies to connections

Comment: If the connection in , say, a terminal block is a bit loose the resistance can increase without it opening completely, it is thus “unsound”.

Answer (score 0):

Interchangeability.

If you have a number of thermocouples of the same type, but different length wires, all heated to the same temperature, then the open circuit voltages will all be the same, the short circuit currents will vary with the length of the wires, whether or not any are being used with extension leads or multiplexers, and the contact resistance at any connectors.

That's true for measurement thermocouples. For gas burner flame failure thermocouples, we do use the output current into a low resistance hold-in coil in the burner. Here interchangeability is taken care of by specifying the specific part number of the thermocouple, and contact resistance by using a screw-in coaxial connector (at least on my hob).